# Making a form that users enter a value into text boxes a certain number of times

Tags: vb.net

I have a series of text boxes that are hidden, except one which users enter a value into. After a button is pressed, this text box disappears and the rest appear. From there, I want users to be able to enter different values into each text box. These values will be saved as variables. From there, users press a button and enter new values into the text boxes, until values have been entered into the text boxes for each number up to the first value entered into the hidden text box.
I'm not sure how else to explain this, but please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if im wrong. i think you want an input in different textbox?
Like textbox1 = 1, textbox2 = 2 and so on. If this is right then try this.

Lets try this to your 3 textbox for an example.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    If TextBox1.Visible = True Then
        If Trim(TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then
            TextBox1.Visible = False
            TextBox2.visible = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Required")
            'or user error provider.
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If textbox2.visible = True Then
        If Trim(TextBox2.Text) <> "" Then
            TextBox2.Visible = False
            TextBox3.visible = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Required")
            'or user error provider.
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'and so on
End Sub
```

hope this is what you want. just basic but maybe usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the workflow of what you want to accomplish in JavaScript. VB.Net has similar functions to Visibility. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748821(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

In the visual editor you can create buttons and add Click events to them, this is basic so I won't tell you how to do it. Google if you can't.

`var options = document.getElementsByClassName("options");`

```
var optionsSetOne = document.getByClassName('optionsSetOne');
```

This will select all your options. Now that you have all your options selected and in a variable called `options` you can play around with the `visibility`, as the user progresses thought the buttons.

First I would set all my options to `hidden` with:

```
options.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

After the users progresses and clicks the button, I will make the first set of the `options` visible. With:

```
$('#buttonOne').click(function(){
       optionsSetOne.style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

This is the basic workflow of what you want to accomplish, you have to figure out how to save all the information the user gives to you.

Comment: @CrushSundae Overlooked that, I changed my answer to fit the theme. The workflow is the same, it is actually more intuitive in VB.Net because of the visual editor and the selection of methods to use on buttons, text-fields etc.

Comment: Be careful in answering questions because it can mislead future visitors of questions.

Comment: @Robert the question tag is vb.net so base your answer in that tag. LOL.